# How to set alignment of a form or control in xamarin.forms like windowsphone FlowDirection="rtl"?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I start a xamarin cross-platform app in visual studio 2017 via xamarin.forms and i`v some localization issue on it.
Question is that, how to set alignment of a form or control in xamarin.forms like windowsphone FlowDirection="rtl"?
I also find some ways for it like:

```
public interface ILocalize
    {
        CultureInfo CurrentCulture { get; set; }
        CultureInfo CurrentUICulture { get; set; }
        CultureInfo GetCurrentCultureInfo();
        CultureInfo GetCurrentCultureInfo(string sLanguageCode);
        void SetLocale();
        void ChangeLocale(string sLanguageCode);
    }
```

...
in app.cs:

```
DependencyService.Get<ILocalize>().ChangeLocale("fa-IR");
```

or this:

```
    public class Localize
{
    static readonly CultureInfo ci;

    static Localize()
    {
        ci = DependencyService.Get<ILocalize>().CurrentCulture;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = ci;
    }

    public static string GetString(string key, string comment)
    {
        ResourceManager temp = new ResourceManager("MyLocalization.Resx.AppResources", typeof(Localize).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

        string result = temp.GetString(key, ci);

        return result;
    }
}

public interface ILocalize
{
    CultureInfo CurrentCulture { get; set; }
    CultureInfo CurrentUICulture { get; set; }
    void SetLocale();
}
```

but these ways do not solve my problem.

**Edit1**: I found a good sample for it but it`s not free:
https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/SlideOverKit

Comment: Check the next solution: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/61652/rtl-layout

Comment: It _is_ free; http://www.michaelridland.com/xamarin/slideoverkit-is-now-free-and-open-source/